# Fullwidth image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slider

My page has a 1000px container for the header(above the red box in below image) and the content(below the red box in the image attached). Those containers are fixed width. But I need to setup a image slider that will be displaying the images in full width.

I mean, I will be including a much wider image. Say, 1800x200 px. So, if the user's screen resolution(width) is less than or equal to 1000px, then the middle portion of the image would be displayed and the image slider should be 1000x200 px in size(resized). But if say the user's screen resolution is 1300(width), then the image slider should be resized displaying the center portion of the image and the slider container would be of size 1300x200 px in size!

Since there are lots of jQuery plugins already available, I thought of not to reinvent the wheel. So tried many jquery sliders. But none of them seems to be meeting my above needs. Or am I missing some settings in those sliders that I tried?

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Long story short. You close your container before the slider and reopen it after the slider. Or you will have to use js to calculate the width and spacing, so you can move the slider with negative margin or something like that. But the most clean way is to close the contianer and reopen it again.

Comment: They are three separate containers. First and the last are set to fixed width 1000px and set margin to `margin: 0 auto;` to center in the screen. My problem is only with the slider!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add an extra outer container? Then center the 1000px container within the outer one.
Then when you resize the window the image slider will respond to the outer container and the inner container stays centered.

```
outerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    .....
}

innerContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto; /*or left:50% right:50%*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap all div in .wraaper div and define width 100%.

```
 .wrapper{width:100%;}
```

and in inner div you have to define section using an

```
 .inner(width: 1000px;)
```

where you need 100% slider dont use this .inner class.

this is help for you.